# how do I resolve a global method provided by a typescript Vue plugin in a component

Tags: vuejs2

I have created a very simple plugin in typescript for a Vue project:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

export const AuthPlugin = {
  install (Vue: any, options: any) {
    Vue.login = () => {
      console.log('login(): ' + options.domain)
    }

    Vue.logout = () => {
      console.log('logout(): ' + options.domain)
    }

    Vue.getUserInfo = () => {
      console.log('getUserInfo(): ' + options.domain)
    }
  }
}
```

That `any` on Vue bugs me but I can see no way around it for now. I insert the plugin in main.ts:

```
Vue.use(AuthPlugin, {
  domain: domain,
  clientId: clientID
})

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

and use the global methods in a component:

```
  private login (): void {
    Vue.login()
  }
```

but this generates a compiler error - it runs fine and as expected, but does spam the console:

```
106:9 Property 'logout' does not exist on type 'VueConstructor<Vue>'.
    104 |   private logout (): void {
    105 |     // Vue.prototype.$auth.logout()
  > 106 |     Vue.logout()
        |         ^
    107 |   }
```

Am missing something? How do I add a reference to the Vue constructor? Note that if in the `install()` method I set the functions up as instance methods I can refer to them as `Vue.prototype.$login()` just fine without compiler errors.

Answer (score 0):

1. Vue as any

You should be able to import to Vue and use it as the type in the install function:

```
import _Vue from "vue"; 
install(Vue: _Vue, ...
```

2. Type declaration

By creating a declaration file for your plugin(ex: auth.d.ts), you can add your additions to the VueConstructor.

```
declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    login: () => void;
    logout: () => void;
    getUserInfo: () => void;
  }
}
```

Source:
https://www.mistergoodcat.com/post/vuejs-plugins-with-typescript